# Python: inserting a 2D list inside another replacing content

Tags: python, list, matrix

I've written a small (destructive) function that takes two 2D lists (or "grids" as I call them) and a set of coordinates. It inserts the first grid inside the second grid, assumed to be as big or bigger as the first one (no checks implemented). The coordinates denote the top-left corner of the first grid.

```
def insert_grid(subj, obj, cords=(0, 0)):
   u, v = cords
   h = len(subj)
   w = len(subj[0])
   for y in range(0, h):
      for x in range(0, w):
         obj[u + y][v + x] = subj[y][x]
```

I was wondering if there was a cleaner, more pythonic way to achieve the same effect. The standard lib methodology would as always be prefered above everything else.

Thank you. Alisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify slightly:

```
def insert_grid(subj, obj, cords=(0, 0)):
    u, v = cords
    w = len(subj[0])        
    for index, row in enumerate(subj, u):
        obj[index][v:v+w] = row
```

This replaces all columns in a row in one go.

Comment: Yes, I really should make using slices my second nature. C mindset doesn't change fast.